# How do I add a user to the "sudo" group?

Tags: sudo, user-management, groups

In `/etc/sudoers` I see this:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command after they have
# provided their password
# (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
# it further down)
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

So how do I add a user to that `sudo` group?

Comment: Is anyone else here trying to get sudo to work with no password on ubuntu 17?

Comment: @AdamF [look here](https://askubuntu.com/a/147265/344926). Next time ask a new question if you want a speedier response.  **;-)**

Comment: Coffe-grinder: would you mind changing your acceptance to the most highly upvoted answer as that's a better way to do it? (no password at all)

Answer (score 321, accepted):

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo <username>
```

The `a` is very important. Without it they'll be removed from all other groups. You will need to either restart your shell/terminal or log out and back in for this to take effect.

See also:

- [How can I add a new user as sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line)

Comment: I did what u recommended, but terminal told me `bash: sudo: command not found`, why?

Comment: @Teifi, that means you probably don't have `sudo` installed or, for some weird reason, it's not in your path. What happens when you run `which sudo`?

Comment: New terminals were not enough. Ended up rebooting for another reason and now it works. Probably log-out/in.

Comment: I know `a` is for append, but i think it will be more usefull to have append as default behavior. Creating an alias is easy so that will be the way to have `groupadd group` then just append it. I did the command without -a once today as i didn't remember the `-a` argument.

Comment: Although this is an Ubuntu forum, For CentOS I had to do `sudo usermod -aG sudo <username>`. Because there was no easy way for me to find this out.

Comment: "The a is very important." This would have been nice to know before I rebooted my machine.

Answer (score 55):

You can either use the user management GUI for it (same place where you create users), or use `sudo adduser <username> sudo` in the command line.

Comment: This is also referred to in the ubuntu documentation on [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) albeit they refer to the admin group instead of the sudo group

Comment: +1: this is the most easy-to-remember, simple and intuitive way to add a user to a group!

Comment: This gives me an error saying ```Usage: adduser [options] LOGIN\n
       adduser -D\n
       adduser -D [options]\n```

Answer (score 24):

You can also use a graphical interface. Click on the gear on the top right of the panel, then select "System Settings" and then "User Accounts"

You need to click the little unlock button to be able to edit things in this window. Then click on the person's account and select the proper dropdown for "Account Type"

[image]

Comment: I have Ubuntu 10.10 but my graphic interface is someway locked. It opens but I when buttons are pressed nothing happens. I suppose is something related to the privileges (I'm actually sudoer). How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you click the 'unlock' button?

Comment: Nice animation! I'd like to do such a gif animation to show new features of my web app ? I'm on Lubuntu 16.04...

Answer (score 22):

Its really simple if you are using Unity as your desktop environment.

If you have created a user already then you can simply change it from *Standard* to *Administrator*, else make sure that you selected *Administrator* when creating a new one.

<sub>Don't forget to unlock before trying to change it</sub>

[image]

Comment: Very cool looking GIF animation! +1 How did you do it? Moved the question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234217/how-to-do-gif-animations-for-instructions-and-learning-purposes-over-gui/234219#234219).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/123515/25863

Answer (score 4):

`sudo gpasswd -a $USER sudo`

Answer (score 3):

I am late to the party, but this answer might help someone that uses Ubuntu inside a Docker container.

I recently created a Docker container based on Ubuntu 16.04.1.

By default, the Docker Ubuntu image is a stripped down version of Ubuntu, which does not have a vast majority of common tools including `sudo`.

Besides, by default, the user is logged in to the Docker container as root.

Therefore, I started the container with the `docker run` command, and installed the 'sudo' package:

```
root@default:/# apt-get install sudo
```

Running the command `adduser myuser sudo` reported error `adduser: The user 'myuser' does not exist.`.
After reading this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/389849/333806), I first ran the command to create the user:

```
root@default:/# adduser myuser
```

Then ran the following command:

```
root@default:/# adduser myuser sudo
Adding user `myuser' to group `sudo' ...
Adding user myuser to group sudo
Done.
```

The user myuser was successfully added to the sudo group.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I setup a non-root user with the base image of `ubuntu:18.04`:

```
RUN \
    groupadd -g 999 foo && useradd -u 999 -g foo -G sudo -m -s /bin/bash foo && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g' && \
    echo "foo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
    echo "Customized the sudoers file for passwordless access to the foo user!" && \
    echo "foo user:";  su - foo -c id
```

What happens with the above code:

- The user and group `foo` is created.
- The user `foo` is added to the both the `foo` and `sudo` group.
- The `uid` and `gid` is set to the value of `999`.
- The home directory is set to `/home/foo`.
- The shell is set to `/bin/bash`.
- The `sed` command does inline updates to the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow `foo` and `root` users passwordless access to the `sudo` group.
- The `sed` command disables the `#includedir` directive that would allow any files in subdirectories to override these inline updates.

Comment: Oh, gheeze. Yours is the kinda place I used to _dream_ about back when my hat was a darker shade of midnight. Where do you wor- actually? Never mind. Neither of us need that.

Answer (score 1):

Use usermod. Add the sudo permission with the following command:

```
usermod -aG sudo <your username>
```

Please note that you'll have to use the root account to do this or use another account that has sudo permissions. If you don't have access to another account for some reason and you don't know the root password, you'll need an Ubuntu (or another Linux distro) live CD and then you'll need to chroot into your Ubuntu filesystem and run the above command from inside the chroot.