# How to create a user with root privileges in bash?

Tags: root, users, privileges

I have run the following commands:

```
sudo groupadd -r testgroup
sudo useradd -g testgroup -M -r testuser
```

Notice the `-r` option, which according to the `man` page:

> -r
>       Create a system account.

Assuming I have a user account with root privileges, I then run:

```
sudo -u testuser cat /dev/input/mouse0
```

However, I get:

> cat: /dev/input/mouse0: Permission denied

Running the same command as root provides the expected output (garbled output from the mouse driver).

How can I create a user with root privileges?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a new user as sudoer using the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Haven't tried it but this should create a new user and add them to the `sudo` group, which if your `/etc/sudoers` is as default, should mean they're allowed to use `sudo` with their password (just like the standard first user):

```
sudo adduser --group sudo newusername
```

If you've already created the user, you can just run:

```
sudo adduser existing_user sudo
```

`man adduser` will show you some of the other billion permutations and combinations of arguments this tool has.

**Note:** If you use Ubuntu 11.10 or older, you should use the `admin` group instead of `sudo`.

Comment: Ah... no wonder it wasn't working.

Comment: For 12.04 (Precise) and newer: The default group for root privileges is sudo but admin will work too. However, new installs won't have the admin group created at all.

Comment: On **Ubuntu 14.04** I get `adduser: Specify only one name in this mode.` when executing `sudo adduser --group sudo ubuntu`

Comment: Also on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS it does not work.

Comment: As @Yura said, in response to the command `adduser --group sudo username` is the message `adduser: Specify only one name in this mode.` **This is probably a failure** because subsequently it is possible to add that same user via the command `adduser username`. This was observed on 16.04. The way to add a new user as a sudoer might require 2 commands: `adduser username && adduser username sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

I found some sites where they do the: `sudo adduser paul admin`

but my linux does not have the admin group so I use:

```
sudo adduser paul sudo
```

Answer (score 2):

"System account" just means that the user will get an UID (user identifier) from a reserved range, it doesn't give any extra permissions. The right way to elavate privileges is to use sudo, as described by Oli.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
sudo adduser robert && sudo adduser robert sudo
```

Creates the user and adds him/er to the sudoer list

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo usermod -a newuser -G sudo
```