# how to make the gnome user as root in ubuntu

Tags: gnome, permissions

on my local Ubuntu 20 desktop i want my user to be root to have access to any place in PC and dont need the sudo and the password to be entered every time i run any command and in some parts of GUI i face read only files which i want to have full access to all of the parts of the os with the GUI .

i want to know if there is any way to login with the root user in gnome or give the custom user the exact same permissions that root user has .

the reason i need that is because in some applications when i install them they need root permissions to build some dir which they fail and  its so hard to fix them .

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32749/how-to-create-a-user-with-root-privileges-in-bash) answer your question?

Comment: i already did this but my user is not root and i always need to enter password for my user

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS gnome version 3.36.3 and this is the link i downloaded from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=20.04.1&architecture=amd64

Comment: *"they need root permissions to build some dir which they fail and its so hard to fix them"* this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)