# how to redo the initial boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, users

I just bought a DELL computer with UBUNTU 16.04. When I did the first boot I made an error entering the wifi credentials. Then the initial setup stop. I have no user created. I cannot do nothing exept open a guest session.

How can I redo the initial boot?
or How can I create a first user?

Thank you

Comment: It is better to ask Dell support for that.

Comment: Can you boot recovery mode to a terminal? ` sudo oem-config-gtk` or reset user: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140513/how-can-i-regain-admin-privileges

Comment: Dell support send me a link ...http://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cabsdt1/HOW12105
It do exactly what I want ... but I don't have the option "restore ubuntu 16.04 to factory state in my grub. Any advice on how to get to that option ?