# Elevation issue password always wrong?

Tags: login, security, password

ubuntu Newbie - I install OS using one account and then later created a second account made administrator with auto login and no password, then I logged in using new account and deleted old account. Now when ever I go to do anything it wants elevation and no matter what you type in the password field wont work. Any suggestions outside of scrapping it and installing Windows?

Comment: If you're looking for something less secure that won't bother you with passwords then Windows is the way to go. Better still is give Ubuntu another try by reinstalling and go with the default setup, until you are comfortable making changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need add the new user to the "sudoers" file (or the admin group).  You are  probably running into a situation where this new user doesn't have permission to run the "sudo" command.

You are going to need to get to a root shell. This link will show you how:
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword/

That ^ is for resetting a password, but it describes how to get to the root prompt.

Once you have your root promt you can refer to this link:
[How can I add a new user as sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer)

More specifically (from said post):

```
sudo adduser <username> admin
```

Then reboot the machine:

```
init 6
```

Run that ^ at the root prompt.  Let it boot normally, log in as the "new" user and give it a shot.  You should be able to "elevate" (sudo) now.