# Lost sudo privileges

Tags: sudo, vsftpd

Last night I was working on installing vsftpd on my Ubuntu 12.10 server. I shutdown last night and when I booted up this morning I seemed to have lost the abilities to sudo anything. It just says, "**** is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported."
Now I wasn't messing with any sudo files, just /etc/vsftpd.confg and /etc/shells. So how did I seemingly lose sudo ability? I'm rather new to Linux in general, but I'm picking it up quick.

Comment: can you paste the output of `groups <USERNAME> | grep sudo` here ? just replace <USERNAME> with your actual username.

Comment: if your not in the sudoers file you could use the rescue mode and put yourself back in.

Comment: @Gufran Nothing printed out when I typed that in with my username.

Comment: @Goddard Goddard I'll look into that.

Comment: @Goddard It worked! I remember last night I was unknowingly added myself to another group which must have removed me from sudo. I got in through recovery mode and was able to change it. Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion: use the `visudo` command to edit the `sudoers` file. It will check the syntax before it will apply the changes. It will be less likely to lock yourself out this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your not in the sudoers file you could use the rescue mode and put yourself back in.

IT should be as simple as going into rescue mode and using the root account to add your account to the sudoers file

Here is that info 
[How can I add a new user as sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line)