# Ubuntu Administration Privilege?

Tags: sudo

I'm a newbie to linux. I have installed ubuntu 12.10. How can i have administrative privileges since i am the Administrator.

On windows if you're the administrator running and installing an application is easy. in ubuntu launching an application requires an administrative privileges..

can someone enlighten me please, how do i go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the information regarding how you tried to install an application in Ubuntu, i.e, is it via Ubuntu software center, commandline, or some other method?

Comment: Put your password in the window. When ubuntu is asking for password, that means you are doing something sensitive. You should know what you are doing before doing it.

Comment: This answer can help you with installing applications, and getting admin privileges: http://askubuntu.com/a/258177/11932

Comment: thanks, will look at the link provided. i guess linux is not as easy as i thought would be...

Comment: No brother Linux is very than windows. Trust me. It's just a new world but same environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can become admin in Ubuntu with `sudo -i`. 
If you want to launch any application as root then
application can be launched as follows

```
sudo application_name
```

If it is a GUI application then launch it with

```
gksudo application_name
```

Installing application can be done from apt-get ,aptitude,Software center , synaptic package manager.

From apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install application_name
```

From aptitude

```
sudo aptitude install application_name
```

Software center and synaptic are GUI applications.

NOTE: You should have clear knowledge on which application can be launched as admin.

Comment: hai jai, thanks, so everytime i launch an app from the terminal i have to add sudo? can't i give the privilege for good so next time i launch app with using sudo?

Comment: If you want to launch the app as admin then you must use sudo before the application name.

Comment: @jeret, you could do that with the use of aliases. Just go into your .bashrc file in your home folder and put an alias there to run whichever command you wish to run as root. For example: If you wish to run 'apt-get' as root always, you can add the line "alias apt-get='sudo apt-get'". You might need to restart the terminal for this to take effect. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Chirag64 actually to update the changes of bashrc we need to do `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @Jai, You can do that to apply the changes in the current terminal instance itself. But if you start a new instance, it will automatically apply the configured changes from .bashrc everytime it starts.

Comment: Welcome brother.