# Ubuntu shut down without using the GUI

Tags: shutdown, root

I'm trying the "poweroff" keyword to shut down my Ubuntu. The terminal produces the following:

```
jay@ubuntu:~$ poweroff
poweroff: Need to be root
```

How can I root my pack?

Comment: additionally, you can edit the sudoers file to do the job without typing password everytime.

Comment: "root" is a fundamental concept in linux that you really need to understand: http://www.linfo.org/root.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Administration Privilege?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/267636/ubuntu-administration-privilege); more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 5):

That message is telling to use sudo, you need to do

```
sudo poweroff
```

More info look at [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/poweroff)