# Authentication failed with the correct password and now I cannot use sudo anymore

Tags: 12.04, authentication, users

Recently I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (first time on Ubuntu).

I have my normal "administrator", and another Guest account.

I was experimenting today with the user accounts, and set my "administrator" account to "standard" in user account settings.

Now whenever something asks me for authentication, it gives me failed message.

I am using the same old password, didn't create new accounts, just changed privileges.
I'm sure that the password is correct, because I can still log in.

I tried logging in to root from Terminal, but it gave me that I'm not one of the `sudoers`.

Comment: This appears to be a permissions error. [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/7484/62364) may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sudoers` file works normally via group membership of a user.

As default, you have the following configuration in ubuntu:

```
 # Members of the sudo group may gain root privileges
 %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

As I understand your description, you have dropped the group membership for the *sudo* group.

Hopefully you have left over another account which is member in the sudo group.
If this is true, you can use the following command to fix your user:

```
 sudo usermod -a -G sudo  USERNAME
```

If you have given your root user an explicit password (non standard in ubuntu), you can also invoke:

```
 su -c usermod -a -G sudo  USERNAME
```

If both isn't possible, you may do the following:

1. boot your computer with a live/rescue cd (see also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)
2. mount your root partition (aka `/`) to e.g. `/mnt`
3. `chroot /mnt usermod -a -G sudo USERNAME`

Comment: At the moment i don't have any administrator accounts (so I assume no sudo members ? )
As i said earlier, the terminal says that my current account "standard" is not a sudoer.

what do you mean by rescue CD ?
I booted from my USB in it bootable version (one i used for installation of OS)
i only get installation wizard

Answer (score 0):

Write `sudo passwd` in the terminal - it asks your current password , then it asks a new password for the super user. It seams like Ubuntu allows you to work without a super user privileges on start. But when you need it - you have to make a password. It is the same with Windows administrator politics if you are familiar with it.

Answer (score -2):

You do not have a root password. Open a terminal and type `sudo passwd root` then hit the enter and set the password.

Comment: **This will not work** - because the OP can't use `sudo` in the moment.

Comment: sudo passwd root Its works for me