# How add user a sudo group

Tags: permissions

I accidentally removed the default user system, ubuntu, from the sudo group. How can I do to regain root access?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set new password for root user using [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/)

After that go back to your system

Use:

`su root`

and enter password you set on previous step

Then [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line) to add your user to sudo