# how to install ubuntu on vmware workstation?

Tags: 13.10

i have tried to install ubuntu on a VMWare workstation, but once finished it entered the console and not the UI of ubuntu, and it was installed with a root user.

i would like to change this to access ubuntu as a normal user

Comment: try `starx` command.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are root you can make any changes you need.

First add your non-root user, and add them to the sudoers group:

# useradd -d /home/testuser -m testuser

# passwd testuser

# adduser testuser sudo

Then you can install one of the virtual packages for the GUI of your choice, do this as either your root or your non-root user via sudo:

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-cache search ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop - The Ubuntu desktop system
edubuntu-desktop - educational desktop for Ubuntu
kubuntu-desktop - Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system
lubuntu-desktop - Lubuntu Desktop environment
xubuntu-desktop - Xubuntu desktop system

$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

... go get a drink after you accept the prompt.

$ startx

See for more details:

- http://www.ehow.com/how_5745914_convert-ubuntu-server-desktop.html
- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/add-a-user-on-ubuntu-server/
- [How can I add a new user as sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line)
- [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)