# How do I add a standard user into sudoers' file using `echo`?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I was doing through a terminal tutorial. There was explained about `echo` command and he mentioned something about adding your name to the `sudoers` file using `echo >>`. I am just wondering what it was? Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: I went to /bin and typed ls and the first file was bash so i think i should type echo jatin >> bash but i am not sure so just asking? :|

Comment: Please, don't ever do this!

Comment: 1) do not _ever_ try to `echo` something `>> /bin/bash` that will break your shell. 2) Do not _ever_ use `echo` to modify `sudoers`, use `visudo` instead. If you found a guide telling you to use `echo` for this, change guides and ignore anything else it recommends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Not Recommended:

First login as root using the following command:

```
sudo -i
```

Then type:

```
echo "username ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Change `username` with your user name.

It will add the `username` to `sudoers` file.  But doing this may lock out you  from `sudo`.

#### Recommended:

If you want to edit your `/etc/sudoers` use `visudo`

`sudo visudo`

You can use  `/etc/sudoers.d` instead of modifying `/etc/sudoers`.

For more see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line).

Comment: Realy realy thank you but how can a standard user do it

Comment: Only users having root privileged can do it,standard users can't.

Comment: Downvoted because the way you have suggested to use sudo simply won't work in this context (it is the redirect `>>` that needs elevated permissions)

Comment: @steeldriver Now it will work

Comment: Although that will work, the "problem" is that sudo will not allow redirect directly. You can use tee or sudo bash -c "echo >> ..."