# problem in netstat

Tags: 13.04, sudo, hadoop

I tried to check configured ports from hadoop user as, `sudo netstat -p1ten | grep java`

But, I am getting result as,

`[sudo] password for hadoopz: 
hadoopz is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

How to get sudo permission for hadoop user ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the user `hadoopz` to the sudoers list.

```
sudo adduser hadoopz sudo
```

Logout and login back to take effect.

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line)