# Installing composer globally permission denied

Tags: software-installation, composer

I'm following the steps in [get composer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) and I want to install composer globally and give me this error.

```
   mv: cannot move ‘composer.phar’ to ‘/usr/local/bin/composer’: Permission denied
```

So what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

to move the file to the specified location(`/usr/local/bin/composer`). You will be prompted to enter your password after you enter this command. (See the note after the command).

`sudo` is used to execute privileged commands and requires the user who is executing this command present in the [sudoers list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line).

If you encounter an error such as this:

```
user is not in the sudoers list. This incident will be reported
```

You will need to ask your administrator to run this command for you as you are not privileged enough to run this command.

Answer (score 0):

if you run it on external server than don't move your composer.phar
instead use below command

```
php composer.phar update
```

Answer (score 0):

try to logout on your server and sign in again then try to install again

1. php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
2. php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '906a84df04cea2aa72f40b5f787e49f22d4c2f19492ac310e8cba5b96ac8b64115ac402c8cd292b8a03482574915d1a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
3. php composer-setup.php
4. php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"