# How I can Install csh as a non-root user?

Tags: software-installation, csh

I need csh for installing a package but I am not root user... I want to install it for my user.

I installed csh_20070713.orig.tar.gz, csh_20070713.diff.gz and csh_20070713-2ubuntu1.dsc
But there is not dpkg-source command...

then I did following procedure:

```
untar *.tar.gz
mv csh_20070713.orig csh_20070713
mkdir csh_20070713/debian
gunzip csh_20070713.diff.gz
patch -p0 < csh_20070713.diff
chmod +x csh_20070713/debian/rules
```

I do not know what should I do next! I used make and make install command in csh_20070713 directory and also debian directory but nothing happened...

Comment: Hi! What do you mean with "nothing happened"?

Comment: when I used make file, the result is: *** missing seperator. Stop

Comment: The makefile for csh appears to use a (BSD-style?) `.if ... .endif` construct which doesn't seem to be supported by GNU make - you may have better luck building `tcsh` instead. Also, try `apt-get source tcsh` (which doesn't need sudo) - if the source repositories are enabled that will be easier than manually downloading an patching. Then `./configure --prefix=$HOME` and `make install` in the patched source directory. You may need to make a symlink from `$HOME/bin/tcsh` to `csh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `Makefile` provided with the `csh` source package uses some (possibly BSD-derived) features that are not supported by `GNU make`, which make building it on an Ubuntu system challenging. An easier alternative is probably to build the `tcsh` package

```
DESCRIPTION
       tcsh  is an enhanced but completely compatible version of the Berkeley UNIX
       C shell, csh(1).
```

If your system's administrator has enabled the necessary source repositories, it *may* be possible for you to download and patch the source automatically using

```
apt-get source tcsh
```

which shouldn't require `sudo` as it will download into to the current directory. If that's not possible, then the source for the `tcsh` package should be available via `git` from `git://git.debian.org/git/collab-maint/tcsh.git`

Once you have the patched source, enter the top-level directory and configure it to build in your home directory e.g.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

This will cause the `tcsh` binary to be installed in `$HOME/bin`, which is likely already in your PATH. You can specify a sub-directory under $HOME if you prefer, or anywhere else that you have write and execute permissions, but you will need to make sure that directory is also added to your PATH. If that all goes well, then

```
make install
```

Finally, you may need to create a symbolic link from `tcsh` to `csh` in order for other programs to find it as the default `csh` implementation e.g. assuming you installed to `$HOME/bin`

```
ln -s tcsh ~/bin/csh
```

Answer (score -1):

I noticed some things about what you did.  There is an easier  way to get this installed.
you can simply install csh by going to your terminal.  Then type `sudo apt-get install csh`
To make your csh a default option on boot type in a terminal `which csh`.

To enter into csh terminal just go to the regular terminal and input `csh`.

[From a how to web site.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-csh-shell-on-linux/)

Comment: I am not root user, and this is my problem ... thanks for this useful link

Comment: you dont need to be root user just use `sudo` like I type

Comment: you are right but the result is: Your user is not in the sudoers file :| and nothing happen... thanks again

Comment: then look at this and get back at me
http://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line/7484#7484

Comment: Same problem :| permission denied because I am not admin or root user :)