# Registering another user

Tags: sudo

I need to know the correct command to register another user. When I tried to do this using `sudo adduser username` it returned NAME_REGEX[_SYSTEM] configuration variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a new user as sudoer using the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

`adduser` adds user to a group. Use `sudo useradd username` to add user onto the system