# Eclipse installation process - initial "sudo mv eclipse /opt" Not working

Tags: software-installation, root, eclipse, mv

I am following this thread:
[How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

I downloaded `eclipse-jee-mars-1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz` into `~/Documents` and ran the `tar` command that extracted the package into an `eclipse` folder inside `~/Documents` -- `~/Documents/eclipse` now exists.

I don't have permission to copy this folder to /opt, so I log-in as root with `su -` command and password. As root, I try to execute the `sudo mv eclipse /opt` command but it's throwing the error: `mv: cannot stat 'eclipse': No such file or directory`.

It seems no one has had this problem. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

When you login as `su -` your environment changes, you are now root and current working directory is `/root`

```
skolodya@ubuntu:$ su -                                                         
Password: 
$ pwd
/root
```

What you need to do is `mv /home/$USER/eclipse /opt` . **Note**: change 
`$USER` to your actual user name

Side note: When you run as root you dont need `sudo`. As regular user , without login in to `su -` you could just do `sudo mv ~/Documents/eclipse /opt` and that would do it, because your environment with `sudo` wouldn't change

Comment: If I was allowed, I would give you the uptick. As a sidenote, I used the thread below to add my user in the sudoers file so that I could run the sudo command directly within the folder without logging in as root. http://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line

Comment: @Mr_C_Willy when you create user at installation, you already are in sudo group , you shouldn't need to do that  :)

Comment: When I used sudo as my regular user and put it in my password, it told me that I did not have permission and a log was recorded.

Comment: @Mr_C_Willy Hmm, OK. Well, not you know for future to create a user during installation :)  Glad i could help. Once you can, please leave an upvote if my answer was useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Serg gave the right answer but I'd just like to add that Eclipse is available in the Ubuntu software centre, which will allow you to get automatic updates, unlike downloading the source.

To get Eclipse installed easily, just search for it in the Software Centre (or search for eclipse-platform), or use `sudo apt install eclipse*`.