# Eclipse installation question - .desktop file

Tags: command-line, software-installation, .desktop

Another noob question trying to install Eclipse as per [How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse) that is following right up after this question:
[Eclipse installation process - initial "sudo mv eclipse /opt" Not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724388/eclipse-installation-process-initial-sudo-mv-eclipse-opt-not-working)

I perform the `gedit eclipse.desktop` command, which opens the `.desktop` file. I then copy and paste the following into the file as instructed:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 
Type=Application
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 eclipse44
Terminal=false
Icon=eclipse
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
```

I then try to execute `sudo desktop-file-install eclipse.desktop`, but nothing happens because the file is still open. So, I close it and it throws the error `sudo: desktop-file-install: command not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install desktop-file-utils`

Comment: thanks! I was trying sudo apt-get install desktop-file-install, to no avail, of course. It's weird that I did not find reference to the utils package easier.

Comment: I have uninstalled eclipse, but somehow the eclipse.desktop file still exists, and so does the eclipse on my application list (I have Kubuntu installed, and hence on the Krunner, I can find this) How do I remove it?