# Ubuntu wont start after trying to fix brightness issue

Tags: boot, 18.04, xorg, brightness, backlight

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

I had brightness issues in my Ubuntu so checked out a few forums. From [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts) forum, I followed the instructions and did:

Opened the file `/etc/default/grub` using gedit or any other text editor. Found below line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Changed above line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Also created the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/80-backlight.conf` with contents:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod"     "sna"
    Option      "Backlight"       "acpi_video0"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Now Ubuntu won't start. It shows a black screen with the following boot messages.

```
[   2.601256] VFS: Cannot open root device "mapper/ubuntu--vg-root" on unknown-block(0,0)
[   2.601308] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.15.0-48-generic #51~Ubuntu
[   2.601336] Hardware name: Acer Aspire 47362 / Aspire 47362 BIOS V1.08 08/14/2009
[   2.601375] Call trace:
[   2.601412]  dump_stack+0x58/0x81
[   2.601446]  panic+0x94/0x1e6
[   2.601479]  mount_block_root+0x199/0x234
[   2.601514]  ? calibrate_delay+190/0x4e0
[   2.601546]  ? create_dev.constrprop.7+0x3a/0x53
[   2.601581]  mount_root+0x33/0x35
[   2.601612]  prepare_namespace+0x11b/0x167
[   2.601645]  kernel_init_freeable+0x1b3/0x1c5
[   2.601679]  ? rest_init+0xa0/0xa0
[   2.601711]  kernel_init+0xd/0x100
[   2.601744]   ret_from_fork+0x2e/0x38
[   2.601795]  Kernel Offset: 0x3d000000 from 8x1a000000 from 8xc1000000 (relocation range: 8xc100000-0xf17dfdfff)
[   2.601836]  ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on   
unknown-block(0,0)
```

Comment: Well Updating a System and changing brightness settings are quite different. How can this error occur when all I did was create a xorg.config file and changed an attribute in grub file? Even the recovery mode is locked down. It shows the same error. Please explain what's happening to my computer. I am new to Ubuntu.