# Brightness Controller is not working on Laptop HP Pavilion Dv7 - Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Tags: 18.04, hp, brightness, backlight, hp-pavilion

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4, and since I've installed it the Brightness controller doesn't work.

I press the Function Key + F2 or F3, and even when the animation pops up, and shows increasing or decreasing on the brightness level, doesn't change anything.

[image: Brightness control]

**I've tried these approaches:**

1- Installing `x-backlight` like described on these posts:

[How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/9sdjqr/brightness_control_problems_in_ubuntu_1804_lts/

but none of `x-backlight` commands worked.

2- Creating a .conf file and modifying the /etc/default/grub file: 
[Brightness problem Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts)
But still the brightness controls in Settings don't work.

**Temporal Fix**

Using Brightness Controller
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/05/install-brightness-controller-utility-in-ubuntu-16-04-higher/

It works fine, even if it dims the screen, doesn't feel like when the default brightness controller works well.

**Additional Information**

[image: Notebook Specification]

These are the files in: **/etc/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/**

```
10-amdgpu.conf  10-radeon.conf    70-wacom.conf
10-quirks.conf  40-libinput.conf  80-backlight.conf
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: Can you show `ls -al /sys/class/backlight`