# Brightness control with hotkeys doesn't work. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: brightness

I tried solution here: [Brightness problem Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts)
But it doesn't work.

Lenovo IdeaPad L340.

I have tested it with all 3 drivers. But none works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Brightness control can be achieved with the GNOME shell extension Adjust Brightness Icon as a work around. It places a clickable icon on the top bar which cycles through a number of brightness options.

Install GNOME extensions if you have not already done so and select the extension. This will place an icon on the top bar which allows you to cycle through different settings of brightness.

[image]

If you don't have GNOME extensions installed [this](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/) guide provides a handy reference.

Comment: Does this work to control brightness with hotkeys?

Comment: @vanadium its a work around and I have amended my answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: I can control brightness threw the slide bar. But i can't do it with fn + f11 and fn + f12. That is brightness up and down.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I tried to do it with hotkeys today, it worked! I was surprised and restarted notebook, then it stopped working and I even surprised more. I don't know why it started and stopped working.

Comment: I found out the answer. When I suspend the notebook and turn it on, the hotkeys work. Idk why.