# I cannot find the brightness setting in Ubunutu 20.04 LTS in my Acer Nitro 5 Laptop

Tags: graphics, acer

I am unable to set the brightness level of an Acer Nitro 5 laptop in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in settings or in the  title bar.

Comment: I don't have this particular laptop, but you could try modifying your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` to include `acpi_osi='!Windows 2015'`, like so: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi='!Windows 2015'"`. Then run: `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Until it's resolved, try:
xrandr
..you should get something like:
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2880 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1600x900      60.08*+  59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
   1440x900      59.89
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1440x810      60.00    59.97
   1368x768      59.88    59.85
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
   1152x864      60.00
..and so on
then:
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness 0.95

this works for me, for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, this has been answered for 18.04 and it was the method I used before upgrading to 20.04.

[Brightness problem Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts)