# Brightness controller gone with kernel 5.4.0-42, was working with 5.4.0-41

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, brightness

I am having the common "missing  brightness controller" problem in Ubuntu (no brightness controller in settings, or as a shortcut keys, brightness controller software does nothing,controlling brightness from terminal doesn't work)

To cut a long story short I have tried many solutions documented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts), and the one shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4iN6lCyE6A).

The one ray of hope is when I boot my computer with kernel `5.4.0-41` the brightness controller is there. When I use the default boot with kernel `5.4.0-42` the brightness controller is not there.

What I also notice is that when I run the command `nividia-smi` in the `42` kernel I get the following error message:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. 
Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

In `41` it is fine and returns valid results.

I believe that last time I fixed the disappearing brightness I forced a boot with an old kernel, but this was only temporary until the next update and the brightness disappeared again. Kernel `-42` is the latest version from apt but only boots with low brightness and is hard to see in normal light conditions.

Comment: Thanks f or the formatting. But I'm still pulling my hair on this one.

Comment: After more searching I've found that in the `41` kernel I have a folder:
`sys/class/backlight/nvidea_0`
This is a symbolic link to what appears to control the brightness etc. 
In the non-working `42`this link is missing. 
How do I  make this link appear in kernel `42. 
Obi Wan?

Comment: OK we're on Kernel .47 and still no fix. Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue recently on my Asus ROG with GTX 1080 Ti. The recent kernel update is `5.4.0-51`. I resolved the issue by re-installing the nvidia driver through `ubuntu-drivers` command line:

$ `sudo ubuntu-drivers list` ---> to see what drivers are available

$ `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` ---> to install the recommended driver

Hope this helps!