# Why is my monitor brightness so low, even though I set xbacklight at 100%?

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, brightness

I don't know why, but I'm unable to set the brightness to more than 30%.

The package `xbacklight` does receive the command to set brightness at 100%, but it never actually happens.

**Interesting fact**: if I'm using the laptop without the battery and remove the charger for a second, the brightness spikes to the true 100% state briefly.

**brightness settings** reveals that brightness is around 30%, actually:

[brightness-settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vMF7.png)

`lsb_release -a`:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics" 
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QS57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
03:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 01)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Comment: I wrote an answer on this topic for a prior release (*cosmic* or *disco*) on laptop/device brightness, and how the various commands (I provided them in the answer) work for maybe 85% of the machines tested on, but do nothing on different hardware/chipsets, thus if the default doesn't work for you, you just vary the commands for other options (*in the answer it was using a shortcut to provide brightness/backlight etc control given inbuilt didn't work on the OP's box*).  I can't find the answer (maybe deleted), but you've answered your own question so I didn't look long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**lxQt Brightness Settings** has a master slider, which is used to define the maximum brightness possible for all monitors.

Although, for some reason, I can't use this slider if launching **lxQt Brightness Settings** from any other place then terminal (`$ lxqt-config-brightness`).

Because of that, everytime I would try to increase the value of this master slider, the setting wouldn't be saved and master slider get back to 30%.

As of now, I have launched the applet from terminal and set master slider to 100% and now, I can use 100% brightness on my monitor.

I have no idea why this applet is not working as intended.

[here's the applet master slider I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpOlI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check if some desktop power manager overrides those settings. I don't know for Lubuntu / LXDE, but in Xfce and in KDE there is a "power manager" applet where reducing screen brightness can be defined for various power scenarios: On wall power, on battery, on low battery, on critically low battery.

https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.12/power_management.html

Then there are various suggestions here:

[Brightness problem Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

HTH

Comment: I just realized it is a bug, thanks to the first link! I'll make an update on question body, so you know how it bugged.

Comment: I made an answer, instead.

Comment: Lubuntu hasn't used LXDE (or GTK2) since 18.04, but the question is about a *groovy* system thus LXQt and Qt5 base.  What has LXDE got to do with it?

Comment: @guiverc: Whatever, if you had read what I wrote you would have realized I gave the hint to check the _desktop_'s power manager applet. Don't sidetrack with irrelevant stuff here.