# unable to change brightness on amd integrated gpu

Tags: brightness, amdgpu, i3-wm

I am using i3 window manager on ubuntu.
My laptop has an AMD CPU and integrated GPU and class is amdgpu_bl0.
please help me with the command to change the brightness so that I can bind that in config.
xbacklight -inc 20% does not work I am getting the error "No outputs have backlight property"

Comment: Try `ybacklight`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1041632#1041632 That fixed a similar problem for me. `xbacklight` has stopped working for me at some point, if I recall correctly because of some changes in the dev file system or the drivers that populate it, under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck with the tool [`light`](https://github.com/haikarainen/light). It works also where `xbacklight` doesn't. It is available in the standard ubuntu software repositories of at least version 20.10, so you can install it with

```
sudo apt install light
```

If that does not work on your Ubuntu version, you can install it according to the instructions of the application's [Github page](https://github.com/haikarainen/light).

It is a great tool. You can set a minimum brightness so that you will never fully darken the screen. I use it with much satisfaction on the default Ubuntu desktop to increase/decrease the brightness in smaller steps, with the commands

```
light -U 1
light -A 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share my positive experience with "light".

After installing it as written in a previous post with

```
sudo apt install light
```

To get the current value run:

```
light -G
```

To set the brightness value, use the addition "-v3" to receive verbose messages.

```
light -S 100.00 -v3
```

In my case I had 2 errors:

1. I was missing the folder/subfolder for my video device (I created them using the "mkdir" command)
2. Every time I rebooted, I lost writing permissions on the file

For point "2", I added user to “video” group to enable writing permissions

```
sudo usermod -aG video user
```

Since I had to give this computer to my parents, and that the brightness goes off every time I charge the battery, I created a script to set the brightness to 100% every 3 seconds (script can be enhanced by checking the charging status, etc...).
Script is launched at startup using "cron", since init.d and rc.local methods were not working for me

Create script

```
#! /bin/sh

while true
do
current_brightness=$(light -G)

if ! [ "$current_brightness" = "100.00" ]
then
light -S 100.00
fi

sleep 3
done
```

Launch script at startup

```
crontab -e
@reboot /home/user/Brightness_100.sh
```