# Add user to sudoers

Tags: sudo, visudo

I want to add a user account to sudoers.

I type in

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo username
```

Then I reboot.

I type

```
apt update
```

I get permission denied.

I type

```
sudo apt update
```

Followed by account password and apt update runs.

I thought that adding things to sudoers allows me to run without specifying sudo and entering password?

Comment: Correct. However where in your question did you add "things to sudoers"? See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line on enabling a users to be able to issue ANY command.

Comment: Okay to it does not add "things to sudoers". So

sudo usermod -aG sudo username

Does not give sudo privileges to username?

Comment: What you did is add a user to the group "sudo" enabling that user to use "sudo". That does not remove the need to use "sudo" before a command nor for you to supply a password every 15 minutes ;)

Comment: Ah gotcha I ran 

sudo visudo

And added the line 

username = ALL= (root) NOPASSWD: ALL

That got me where I wanted. Thank you. 

I will change the last ALL to point to what I want to specifically run in BIN. Thank you.

Comment: Adding a user to the `/etc/sudoers/` file is not enough... You will have to add the `NOPASSWORD` tags...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a user to `/etc/sudoers/` just permits this user to invoke commands with `sudo`. Using `sudo` is still required.

Comment: How to make user equal to root, though?

Comment: @TimurGilauri I don't understand your question.