# How to run scheduled task on Ubuntu with line from Laravel

Tags: 14.04

I need to run `sudo php artisan backup:run` and automatically enter password everyday 3pm. I know how to do this on Windows just by using tasks scheduler and set run as admin on the .bat script.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Answer (score 1):

This is *should* be pretty much the same on Ubuntu 14.04 as it is on the latest releases - however, they maybe some differences.

The task is divided into two parts:

- To be able to `sudo` without a password, add the user to the `sudoers` file and allow them to not require a password.
- To run a job automatically, use `cron`.

#### sudoers

Add the user to the sudo group with

```
usermod -aG sudo <username>
```

Change `<username>` to the user that you want to run the job as.

To avoid having to enter the password, edit the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
visudo
```

and add the following line at the end of the file:

```
<username>  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Again, change `<username>` to the user that you want to run the job as.

Note that a better approach would be to create a new sudoers file for your particular user instead, instead of editing the main sudoers file, like so:

```
echo "<username>  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/username
```

For more info see [How to Add User to Sudoers in Ubuntu](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-user-to-sudoers-in-ubuntu/).

See also this question, [How can I add a user as a new sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/7477/348964)

#### cron

cron is very powerful and there are a lot of different options. However, to accomplish your task, here are just the basic essentials:

To edit the crontab, use

```
crontab -e
```

or for a different user, use

```
crontab -u ostechnix -e
```

If you have never run crontab before, you may be asked to choose an editor the first time that you run it.

Then for a 3 pm job add the line

```
0 15 * * * <command-to-execute>
```

So in your case use

```
0 15 * * * sudo php artisan backup:run
```

Save and exit to editor. Then to check the crontab, use

```
crontab -l
```

If you want to change the time the fields are as follows, from the cron man page.

```
       The time and date fields are:

              field          allowed values
              -----          --------------
              minute         0-59
              hour           0-23
              day of month   1-31
              month          1-12 (or names, see below)
              day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)

       A field may contain an asterisk (*), which always stands for
       "first-last".
```

For more info about `crontab`, see [A Beginners Guide To Cron Jobs](https://ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/), or type `man cron`.

See also this question, [How do I set up a Cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2368/348964)