# sudo command throwing 'user is not in the sudoers file'

Tags: permissions, 22.04, sudo, groups

I am on user `myuser` on Ubuntu and it is only assigned to its own group `myuser`. `sudo -i` gives:

```
user is not in the sudoers file
```

I cannot log in to a wifi because it is asking for a password and `myuser` password is failing.

There is no admin on my machine, is there a way to add `myuser` to the other groups without sudo? Is a complete format/reset of the machine necessary?

The os is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I cannot access Grub recovery mode because I do not have sudo access to change `/etc/default/grub` file (recovery mode not loading on holding shift key)

Comment: How come you don't have an user with admin rights?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: What's the output of cat /etc/group | grep sudo?

Comment: @AnthonyKelly the output is `sudo:x:27:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a user as a new sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-user-as-a-new-sudoer-using-the-command-line)

Comment: @bcsta Hmmm.  I think Recovery Mode is going to be the only option.  Did you see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/1165986) that mentioned that it may be the Esc key on UEFI systems?  Also, it can be tricky to time the keypress just right - That answer also mentions needing to try it several times.

Comment: Also, there's a possibility that another bootloader took its place if you ever dual-booted.  Check the BIOS boot order to see if Grub is the default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)