# is not in the sudoers file. this incident will be reported and authentication failure at the same time

Tags: sudo, su

I tried to install something with sudo but I received: ".... is not in the sudoers file. this incident will be reported". I used "su -" and "su root" to fix this problem but I got "authentication failure". What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a user as a new sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-user-as-a-new-sudoer-using-the-command-line)

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Find someone whose account has `sudo` privileges and have them add you to sudoers. Next alternative is to boot the system off of a live image and add yourself to sudoers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Comment: I solved it. First deleted ubuntu and installed again. Then with su root, added myself to the sudoer.  Thank you to everybody that tried to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

The user needs to be in the `sudo` group. Trying `su` and `sudo root` doesn't work because,for security reasons, Ubuntu has disabled the whole idea of a `root` password. You can manage your system easily with a properly configured `sudo`. Read `man sudo sudoers`.

If you don't have access to any UID 0 account, you'll have to reboot into "single user mode", `adduser your_userid sudo`, and reboot again. If you can't use `adduser`, read `man groups`, and, in single user mode, `nano /etc/groups`. Find the line beginning with `sudo:`, append `your_userid` to the the comma-separated userid list after the second colon. If `your_userid` is the only one, no comma is needed.