# I cannot Access sudo on my ubuntu VM

Tags: permissions, sudo, password

When I try to get my account to admin, Every way everyone used to open admin, did not work for me.
When i tried `sudo -i` or `sudo su`, it gave me this output,

```
usbuser123@Ubuntu2USB:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for usbuser123: 
usbuser123 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be recorded
usbuser123@Ubuntu2USB:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for usbuser123: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for usbuser123: 
usbuser123 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be recorded
```

here's an image :
[An image of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Fu1.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a user as a new sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-user-as-a-new-sudoer-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
pkexec visudo
```

pkexec is an alternative of sudo

then add this line under members of group sudo to execute any command  :

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
add this line if doesnt exist 
 %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```