# How to create animated GIF images of a screencast?

Tags: screencast

I've seen animated GIF images of screen casts (like the one below) promoted a few times on this site as a way to improve answers.

[image: Animated GIF image]

What toolchain is being used to create these? Is there a program that does this automagically, or are people taking screencasts, converting them into a series of static frames, and then creating the GIF images?

Comment: [LICEcap (http://www.cockos.com/licecap)](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) is much simpler than any of the solutions below, because it's GUI-based. It's free as in freedom and price. The only downside is that you have to run it via Wine.

Comment: Related: [GIF screencasting; the UNIX way](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113695/1174) from the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: Related: [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](http://superuser.com/a/556031/277135) on SuperUser.

Comment: Is this example screenshot taken on Windows?

Comment: @Clément That was the first thing I noticed, too :)

Comment: I think vokoscreenNG can record desktop to GIF also, but for whatever reason, my 3.0.7 version on Debian 11 wasn't showing the GIF format for recording so I wound up using the Peek program that @stommestack mentioned. Peek installed into Debian 11 easy with the one-liner command that stommestack gave.

Comment: just fyi... MP4 is SMALLER in size than GIF... you can use OBS.. cause I thought GIFs were smaller in size, then downloaded a 50 sec clip it was 7.5mb ... O.O  ... MP4 was quarter of that size on: High Quality, Medium File Size in OBS... you can get it to KiloBytes with MP4 configs

Answer (score 423, accepted):

### [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek)

Is a new application that lets you easily record GIF's from your screen.

[image: peek screencast demo]

Anyway, keep in mind that GIF's have a very limited color palette so it's not a very good idea to use them.

Since Ubuntu 18.10 you can install Peek directly.

```
sudo apt install peek
```

For older versions of Ubuntu, you can install the latest versions of Peek from its [PPA](https://code.launchpad.net/~peek-developers/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peek-developers/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install peek
```

Find more information in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/phw/peek).

Comment: Yes this one is great. its only works with X11 and is targeted at GNOME 3.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf and ExillustX: don't post bug reports here, use the issue tracker where people actually care about seeing them!  Report it here: https://github.com/phw/peek/issues

Comment: This is a great tool.

Comment: @Jop V. how did you do a record of a record?

Comment: @milkovsky I didn't record this. That having been said, I think they used a virtual machine and recorded that.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work on i3wm

Comment: Peek also has an AppImage version. Just download and run it. No installation required!

Comment: You just made my day

Comment: @WongJiaHau For peek to work in i3wm, install compton, and start compton before peek starts.

Comment: seems PPA not support ubuntu 14?

Comment: this record entire screen instead of just a region

Comment: Unfortunately, [Peek is deprecated](https://github.com/phw/peek/issues/1191) since Jan 2023.

Answer (score 282):

### [Byzanz](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/byzanz-record.1.html)

Best software I ever found to record GIF screencasts is Byzanz.

Byzanz is great because it records directly to GIF, the quality and FPS is impressive while maintaining the size of the files to a minimal.

### Installation

Byzanz is now available from the universe repository:

```
sudo apt-get install byzanz
```

### Usage

When it is installed you can run it in a terminal.

This is a small example I did just now with

```
byzanz-record --duration=15 --x=200 --y=300 --width=700 --height=400 out.gif
```

[image]

Comment: I have Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and byzanz 0.1.1-4 comes with it. It's in universe/gnome repository, I found, when I typed "sudo apt-cache showsrc byzanz". I installed it and it works exactly as you demonstrate. Thanks for pointing this cool package out -- is a huge timesaver for developers to demonstrate new features to clients.

Comment: Thanks, nice tool! The colours are not always accurate, but that's a minor detail. I've written a shell script which helps with capturing a window (selected on runtime by the user), posted in [an answer below](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast/201018#201018).

Comment: Byzanz doesn't have any UI! Am I supposed to guess the x, y, width and height of the area I want to record? It's a little ridiculous that in 2014 I'd still have to do this.

Comment: @DanDascalescu No one says you need to use it... I much prefer a terminal than a GUI, what is wrong with that?

Comment: If I want to record a portion of a window, I'll have to guess X, Y, width, height coordinates until I nail down the area I want to record. Super cumbersome.

Comment: @DanDascalescu There's no need to guess. You can use `xwininfo` to get the window properties.

Comment: @RobW "The colours are not always accurate" this was an understatement for me, any way to control this?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I don't know.

Comment: @MarcusMøller: what if I want to record part of a window, not the entire window? Having to manually guess and type coordinates is silly, as evidenced by the fact that this guy wrote [an app that does that for you, and calls byzanz](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211218/29324).

Comment: @DanDascalescu: http://askubuntu.com/a/201018/4066 solves this problem.

Comment: Any way to avoid having to know the duration in advance? When recording I never know in advance how much time it will take.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - for part of a window, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/487725/how-can-i-draw-selection-rectangle-on-screen-for-my-script, can be compiled on Ubuntu 14, you start it, draw a rectangle on screen and it automatically dumps screen coords and a byzanz command with it

Comment: @DanDascalescu This is normal, in Linux it's common to have commandline tools, and GUIs to complement that. GParted for `parted`, `qike-gui` for `ike`, among many others. The fact that somebody wrote an app is great, but a command-line tool is also great, if only for more technically inclined peope (you could build a little parental monitoring tool with it + cron, for example)

Comment: I have recently created a GUI for Byzanz. You can check this out here: https://github.com/zaak/jscreencaster.

Comment: `xwininfo` just shows me the size of the whole window, or I do something wrong. but `xdotool getmouselocation` works for me (on debian) and shows the current location of the mousepointer - nice hack: `watch -t -n 0.0001 xdotool getmouselocation` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37238106/4940240) and just for completeness here ist a "gui-script" for byzanz: https://www.maketecheasier.com/record-screen-as-animated-gif-ubuntu/

Comment: @MarcusMøller and others who came up with geeky replies or upvoted them: the fact that [the Peek answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/833995/116961) to this question overtook this complex Byanz setup shows that user experience matters. Even among Linux folks. PS: I'm a geek too, but I also understand non-geeks.

Comment: this seems discontinued

Comment: @DanDascalescu In 2023, is seems ridiculous to complain about a software that is not the software you want to have that it is not the software you want to have. Feel free to not use it, and/or write it yourself. Oh, and if it is open source software, you can save a whole lot of work by using the existing software as part of building what you want.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I agree very strongly that user experience matters. Somebody has implemented some functionality here. He did not pretend to implement a user interface. It is not his fault that it does not exist. He did not implement it just like I and you did not implement it. It feels wrong to complain that he did not do more of something _because_ he already did something.

Answer (score 237):

First install this:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick mplayer gtk-recordmydesktop
```

those are the required stuff, ImageMagick, MPlayer and Desktop Recorder.
Then use **Desktop Recorder** to capture a portion of the screen/application to use as the screencast.  After the Desktop Recorder has saved the recording into an **OGV video**, **MPlayer** will be used to capture JPEG screenshots, saving them into the 'output' directory.

On a terminal:

```
mplayer -ao null <video file name> -vo jpeg:outdir=output
```

Use **ImageMagick** to convert the screenshots into an animated gifs.

```
convert output/* output.gif
```

you can optimize the screenshots this way:

```
convert output.gif -fuzz 10% -layers Optimize optimised.gif
```

Comment: another way to optimize gif is to use gifsicle: `gifsicle -O in.gif -o out.gif` I just tried and got 100x reduction in file size.

Comment: For those wondering, the first flag in @Yrogirg command is a capital "O", not the digit "0" :)

Comment: The first convert command does not create the gif for me, it says "killed" and just terminates

Comment: @ArtWorkAD See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12623) You should adjust the amount of memory imagemagik consumes.

Comment: Wow, gifsicle just made mine faster but no smaller, and the convert optimize command made it reaaaaally ugly.

Comment: I recommend combining the last two `convert` steps into one: `convert output/* -layers Optimize output.gif`. For me, this sped up processing time as well as made the output file smaller. I don't see any reason to do those steps separately. (I didn't try the `-fuzz 10%` argument.)

Comment: I needed to use `convert <input-files> -limit area 0 -layers Optimize <output-file>`; otherwise `convert` would get `Killed` for out-of-memory reasons.

Comment: Like @MalcolmOcean, the `convert` statement made it beyond hideous.  According to the docs ( http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#layers ), the `optimize` implementation can change over time. But a slightly tweaked `convert` statement with the `-coalesce` flag improved things, but still not to where it was acceptable. I ended up having to use the `-layers optimize-transparency` setting for best results: `convert 'output/*.jpg' -coalesce -layers optimize-transparency optimised.gif`

Answer (score 144):

### [byzanz](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Archive/byzanz/)

#### Overview

This answer contains three shell scripts:

1. `byzanz-record-window` - To select a window for recording.
2. `byzanz-record-region` - To select a part of the screen for recording.
3. A simple GUI front-end for 1.

#### Introduction

Thanks Bruno Pereira for [introducing me to `byzanz`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast/123515#123515)! It's quite useful for creating GIF animations. The colours may be off in some cases, but the file size makes up for it. Example: [40 seconds, 3.7Mb](https://rob.lekensteyn.nl/youtubelyrics/screenshots/40seconds.gif?u).

### Usage

Save one/all of the following two scripts in a folder within your `$PATH`. Here's an example on using the first script to make a screencast of a specific window.

1. Run `byzanz-record-window 30 -c output.gif`
2. Go to the window (alt-tab) you want to capture. Click on it.
3. Wait 10 seconds (hard-coded in `$DELAY`), in which you prepare for recording.
4. After the beep (defined in the `beep` function), `byzanz` will start.
5. After 30 seconds (that's the meaning of `30` in step 1), `byzanz` ends. A beep will be broadcast again.

I included the `-c` flag in `byzanz-record-window` to illustrate that any arguments to my shell script are appended to `byzanz-record` itself. The `-c` flag tells `byzanz` to also include the cursor in the screencast.
See [`man byzanz-record`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/byzanz-record.1.html) or `byzanz-record --help` for more details.

### `byzanz-record-window`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Delay before starting
DELAY=10

# Sound notification to let one know when recording is about to start (and ends)
beep() {
    paplay /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Im-Irc-Event.ogg &
}

# Duration and output file
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    D="--duration=$@"
else
    echo Default recording duration 10s to /tmp/recorded.gif
    D="--duration=10 /tmp/recorded.gif"
fi
XWININFO=$(xwininfo)
read X <<< $(awk -F: '/Absolute upper-left X/{print $2}' <<< "$XWININFO")
read Y <<< $(awk -F: '/Absolute upper-left Y/{print $2}' <<< "$XWININFO")
read W <<< $(awk -F: '/Width/{print $2}' <<< "$XWININFO")
read H <<< $(awk -F: '/Height/{print $2}' <<< "$XWININFO")

echo Delaying $DELAY seconds. After that, byzanz will start
for (( i=$DELAY; i>0; --i )) ; do
    echo $i
    sleep 1
done

beep
byzanz-record --verbose --delay=0 --x=$X --y=$Y --width=$W --height=$H $D
beep
```

### `byzanz-record-region`

Dependency: `xrectsel` from [xrectsel](https://github.com/lolilolicon/xrectsel). Clone the repository and run `make` to get the executable. (If it protests there is no makefile, run `./bootstrap` and the `./configure` before running `make).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Delay before starting
DELAY=10

# Sound notification to let one know when recording is about to start (and ends)
beep() {
    paplay /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Im-Irc-Event.ogg &
}

# Duration and output file
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    D="--duration=$@"
else
    echo Default recording duration 10s to /tmp/recorded.gif
    D="--duration=10 /tmp/recorded.gif"
fi

# xrectsel from https://github.com/lolilolicon/xrectsel
ARGUMENTS=$(xrectsel "--x=%x --y=%y --width=%w --height=%h") || exit -1

echo Delaying $DELAY seconds. After that, byzanz will start
for (( i=$DELAY; i>0; --i )) ; do
    echo $i
    sleep 1
done
beep
byzanz-record --verbose --delay=0 ${ARGUMENTS} $D
beep
```

### Gui version of `byzanz-record-window`

Script with a simple GUI dialogue:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# AUTHOR:   (c) Rob W 2012, modified by MHC (https://askubuntu.com/users/81372/mhc)
# NAME:     GIFRecord 0.1
# DESCRIPTION:  A script to record GIF screencasts.
# LICENSE:  GNU GPL v3 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)
# DEPENDENCIES:   byzanz,gdialog,notify-send (install via sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/byzanz; sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install byzanz gdialog notify-osd)

# Time and date
TIME=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")

# Delay before starting
DELAY=10

# Standard screencast folder
FOLDER="$HOME/Pictures"

# Default recording duration
DEFDUR=10

# Sound notification to let one know when recording is about to start (and ends)
beep() {
    paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/message-new-instant.oga &
}

# Custom recording duration as set by user
USERDUR=$(gdialog --title "Duration?" --inputbox "Please enter the screencast duration in seconds" 200 100 2>&1)

# Duration and output file
if [ $USERDUR -gt 0 ]; then
    D=$USERDUR
else
    D=$DEFDUR
fi

# Window geometry
XWININFO=$(xwininfo)
read X < <(awk -F: '/Absolute upper-left X/{print $2}' <<< "$XWININFO")
read Y < <(awk -F: '/Absolute upper-left Y/{print $2}' <<< "$XWININFO")
read W < <(awk -F: '/Width/{print $2}' <<< "$XWININFO")
read H < <(awk -F: '/Height/{print $2}' <<< "$XWININFO")

# Notify the user of recording time and delay
notify-send "GIFRecorder" "Recording duration set to $D seconds. Recording will start in $DELAY seconds."

#Actual recording
sleep $DELAY
beep
byzanz-record -c --verbose --delay=0 --duration=$D --x=$X --y=$Y --width=$W --height=$H "$FOLDER/GIFrecord_$TIME.gif"
beep

# Notify the user of end of recording.
notify-send "GIFRecorder" "Screencast saved to $FOLDER/GIFrecord_$TIME.gif"
```

See also:

- [byzanz-gui](https://github.com/rhcarvalho/byzanz-gui) by rhcarvalho
- [This other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/833973/349837), another improved version of Rob W's `byzanz-record-region`.

Comment: Are these scripts kept someplace like github?  They're super useful, it'd be nice if they were kept someplace better than text in StackOverflow answer.

Comment: @KFro This is Ask Ubuntu, not SO ;) No, I haven't put them in a git repository, because the scripts themselves are badly documented (for users). The accompanying documentation is included with the answer, so I see no benefit of splitting up the files and documentation in a Git repository.

Comment: Note that `xrectsel` has been separated from FFcast2; it is now and independent repository at https://github.com/lolilolicon/xrectsel

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for the pointer. Feel free to edit my answer to get credit for your findings.

Comment: No more credits for editing, but done ;-).

Comment: Just wanted to say a huge thanks for this - awesome answer and helped me out a lot. [Here's](https://github.com/eightyeight/dotfiles/blob/ubuntu/byzanz/byzanz-record-region) what I ended up with. I like to use `notify-send` as well in case my sound is off.

Comment: Byzanz does not work in 16.04.

Comment: Instead of `beep \n command \n beep`, it would be better to put it like this - `beep \n  ( sleep $DURATION;  beep; ) & \n command`. This is so because even after stopping the recording, the main program could take quite a lot of time in rendering and generating the output before the second beep is heard.

Comment: https://github.com/lolilolicon/xrectsel needs to be compiled, fortunately it is easy to compile, replace the last step with `sudo make install`.

Comment: Any way to avoid having to know the duration in advance? When recording I never know in advance how much time it will take.

Comment: @Masi Byzanz - and these scripts - work just fine for me in 16.04

Answer (score 54):

## [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) ([install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ffmpeg))

One of the best tools I use is `ffmpeg`.  It can take most video from a screencast tool such as `kazam` and convert it to another format.

Install this from *software-center* - it is automatically installed if you install the excellent `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.

Kazam can output in the video formats `mp4` or `webm`.  Generally you get better results outputting in `mp4` format.

### Example GIF making syntax

The basic syntax to convert video to gif is:

```
ffmpeg -i [inputvideo_filename] -pix_fmt rgb24 [output.gif]
```

GIFs converted - especially those with a standard 25/29 frame-per-second can be very large.  For example - a 800Kb webm 15-second video at 25fps can output to 435 MB!

You can reduce this by a number of methods:

#### Framerate

Use the option `-r [frame-per-second]`. For example

```
ffmpeg -i Untitled_Screencast.webm -r 1 -pix_fmt rgb24 out.gif
```

Size reduced from 435 MB to 19 MB

#### File-size limit

Use the option `-fs [filesize]`. For example

```
ffmpeg -i Untitled_Screencast.webm -fs 5000k -pix_fmt rgb24 out.gif
```

**Note**: This is an approximate output file size so the size can be slightly bigger than specified.

#### Size of output video

Use the option `-s [widthxheight]`. For example

```
ffmpeg -i Untitled_Screencast.webm -s 320x200 -pix_fmt rgb24 out.gif
```

This reduced the example 1366x768 video size down to 26 MB

#### Loop forever

Sometimes you might want the GIF to loop forever.

Use the option `-loop_output 0`. For example

```
ffmpeg -i Untitled_Screencast.webm -loop_output 0 -pix_fmt rgb24 out.gif
```

#### Further optimise and shrink

If you use `imagemagick` `convert` with a fuzz factor between 3% and 10% then you can dramatically reduce the image size

```
convert output.gif -fuzz 3% -layers Optimize finalgif.gif
```

### Finally

Combine some of these options to reduce to something manageable for Ask Ubuntu.

```
ffmpeg -i Untitled_Screencast.webm -loop_output 0 -r 5 -s 320x200 -pix_fmt rgb24 out.gif
```

Followed by

```
convert output.gif -fuzz 8% -layers Optimize finalgif.gif
```

### Example

[image: screencast example]

Comment: If you have Docker and your video is `demo.mkv` you can run this commands: `docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/tmp/video/ jrottenberg/ffmpeg -i /tmp/video/demo.mkv -framerate 1/2 -pix_fmt rgb24 -loop 0 /tmp/video/demo.gif`, `sudo chown $USER:$USER demo.gif`

Comment: To me it complains that there is no such option as `-loop_output`...

Comment: +1 Best answer. But one q do you still think `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is excellent ??

Comment: @ParanoidPanda now the option is `-loop`. So it would be `-loop 0`. Here is a working command in Ubuntu 16.04.01 `ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 100x100 -i :0.0+500,500 -pix_fmt rgb24 -loop 0 out2.gif`. `+500,500` is the X,Y position to start the 100x100 rectangle. `xgrab` takes the screen as input.

Answer (score 34):

### Silentcast

[Silentcast](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast) is another great GUI-based tool for creating animated .gif images. Its features include:

- 4 recording modes:

  1. Entire screen
  2. Inside window
  3. Window with decoration
  4. Custom selection
- 5 output formats:

  1. `.gif`
  2. `.mp4`
  3. `.webm`
  4. `.png` (frames)
  5. `.mkv`
- No installation necessary (portable)
- Custom working directory
- Custom fps

### Installation

If you want a regular installation and are running a supported version of Ubuntu you can install Silentcast by PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sethj/silentcast  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install silentcast
```

If you aren't running a supported version of Ubuntu (you should really upgrade!) you will need to download the latest version [from the GitHub page](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/releases) and manually satisfy the dependencies (you can procure yad and ffmpeg from [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager) and [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejon-severinsson/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg) respectively) or, if you are running a slightly more recent version such as 13.10 you could try [downloading the .deb directly](https://launchpad.net/%7Esethj/+archive/ubuntu/silentcast/+files/silentcast_2.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb).

If you're using Gnome you might want to install the [Topicons extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/) to make stopping Silentcast easier.

### Usage

Start Silentcast from your desktop environment's gui or run the `silentcast` command in a terminal. Pick your settings and follow the on-screen prompts. When you're done recording you will be presented with a dialog for optimizing the final output by removing a certain number of frames.

For more in depth usage guidelines take a look at the README, either the [online GitHub version](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/blob/master/README.md) or the local version stored in `/usr/share/doc/silentcast` with zless or your favourite editor.

[image: Example]

### Notes:

Silentcast is still in the development stage and although it is quite stable you might encounter some bugs. If you do please report them [on the project's GitHub issues tracker](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/issues). If you have trouble installing from the PPA and are running a supported version of Ubuntu leave a comment below or [contact the maintainer](https://launchpad.net/%7Esethj/) (me) on Launchpad.

Comment: as soon as I hit 'Stop' it crashes...

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales Can you run it from the command-line and then try? Once it crashes take the output and upload it to http://paste.ubuntu.com and link it back here so I can take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm this works great! It creates a very small (650 KB) .gif file with great resolution outside of open windows as displayed in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/882419/how-can-bash-display-in-ubuntus-unity-system-tray/882420#882420 I might add the poster @Seth is a great guy and helped me in AU general chat room set it up :)

Comment: Is the project abandoned? There hasn't been any commits to the repository in nearly two years.

Comment: @flux unfortunately, between health problems and uni, yes. The repository is currently abandoned. The project on GitHub isn't, however and you can get the latest code there.

Comment: 6 years old abandoned project

Answer (score 8):

There are all sorts of complicated and well-working (presumably) ways to do this listed here. However, I've never wanted to go through that process before nor since. So, I simply use an online converter which suits my needs the few times I need to do so. I've used this site:

http://ezgif.com/video-to-gif

It's not my site and I'm not affiliated with them in any way. They're just the one in my bookmarks and there are many more.

Comment: I like this. I already use simplescreenrecorder to record my desktop for youtube on occassion, so turning the mkv into a gif was easy with this.

Answer (score 8):

I created [`record-gif.sh`](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/record-gif.sh), an improved version of [Rob W's `byzanz-record-region`](https://askubuntu.com/a/201018/22343):

> A lame GUI for [`byzanz`](https://github.com/GNOME/byzanz), improved the user experience (**mouse-selectable area**, record progress bar, **replay-able recording**).

[image: record desktop with shell]

- set recording `duration` ;
- set `save_as` destination ;
- **select –with the mouse–** the area to record ;
- **create a script to replay recording** (cf. `$HOME/record.again`).

#### Install

I also created an installation script

```
curl --location https://git.io/record-gif.sh | bash -
```

Comment: You need to do `sudo apt install autoconf byzanz` before runing this script. it's not installed by default in ubuntu

Comment: @Crantisz thanks, I updated the install script to install `autoconf` and `byzanz`. Could you try it?

Comment: I just tested it on other PC. There isn't git on my fresh-installed ubuntu system. And I don't know why, but the script stops just after second apt-get Y/N question. Can you pack all dependencies in one command?

Comment: @Crantisz the command is an installer script, if you just want record-gif.sh you can [get it from the repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edouard-lopez/record-gif.sh/master/record-gif.sh)

Comment: Bug report: byzanz must be executed prepepended by `GDK_SCALE=1` because it's not HiDPI-aware. https://i.imgur.com/Y1KYZdU.gif Prepending the script also works but is a pita.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install these 3 packages: `imagemagick` `mplayer` `gtk-recordmydesktop`
2. Run **Desktop Recorder** to capture a portion of the screen/application to use as the screencast
3. Download `ogv2gif.sh` from https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/ogv2gif
4. Run: `./ogv2gif.sh yourscreencast.ogv`
5. The GIF file will be put in the same directory

*100% inspired from [maniat1k's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/107735/4066).*

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so in order to also capture mouse clicks, the only thing I found was `key-mon` (via the README of [`screenkey`](https://github.com/wavexx/screenkey)):

- <s>https://code.google.com/archive/p/key-mon</s> https://github.com/critiqjo/key-mon
- `sudo apt-get install key-mon`

Then I:

- Start `key-mon`
- Use [`xrectsel`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487725/how-can-i-draw-selection-rectangle-on-screen-for-my-script/763708#763708) to get the screen coordinates put into a `byzanz` command
- Run the `byzanz` command

... and it looks sort of like this:

[image: out.gif]

Note that `key-mon --visible_click` would draw a circle around the mouse pointer upon mouse click - which I would prefer, but in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS this is somewhat broken, as this circle does not appear and disappear fast enough in order to correctly illustrate the clicks (i.e. mouse presses and releases).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get even fancier, you can use a more sophisticated method than animated gifs using HTMl5 canvas screencasting. The [x11-canvas-screencast](https://github.com/rprichard/x11-canvas-screencast) project will create an html5 canvas animated screen capture.

You may have seen some [famous examples](http://www.sublimetext.com/~jps/animated_gifs_the_hard_way.html) of this tech on the Sublime Text website. `x11-canvas-screencast` takes this method a step further by incorporating tracking of the mouse cursor. Here's a [demo of what x11-canvas-screencast produces](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/rprichard/x11-canvas-screencast/blob/master/example/example.html)

The result is better than an animated gif since it's not limited to the number of colors it has and it takes less bandwidth.

Comment: That is nice and all but you cannot easily share this, e.g. Slack, Twitter etc.

Comment: @ElijahLynn very true. This solution is optimized for high frame rate, low bandwidth, full color depth. It's not portable (to embedding in a tweet for example) as it requires javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I recently created combined version of scripts already posted here.
Basically, it allows you to record screen region, but with simple GUI.

*Thanks for [**Rob W**](https://askubuntu.com/users/45058/rob-w) for providing those cool scripts*

Here's the code (or [gist](https://gist.github.com/Jacajack/b93548694418b9fbc9dd57a425266dbd) if you like):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#Records selected screen region, with GUI

#This is combined version of GIF recording scripts, that can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast
#Thanks to Rob W, and the other author (unmentioned), for creating this lovely scripts

#I do not own any rights to code I didn't write
#                                     ~Jacajack

DELAY=5 #Delay before starting
DEFDUR=10 #Default recording duration
TIME=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S") #Timestamp
FOLDER="$HOME/Pictures/Byzanz" #Default output directory

#Sound notification to let one know when recording is about to start (and ends)
beep() {
    paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/message-new-instant.oga &
}

#Custom recording duration as set by user
USERDUR=$(gdialog --title "Duration?" --inputbox "Please enter the screencast duration in seconds" 200 100 2>&1)

#Duration and output file
if [ $USERDUR -gt 0 ]; then
    D=$USERDUR
else
    D=$DEFDUR
fi

#Get coordinates using xrectsel from https://github.com/lolilolicon/xrectsel
REGION=$(xrectsel "--x=%x --y=%y --width=%w --height=%h") || exit -1

notify-send "GIFRecorder" "Recording duration set to $D seconds. Recording will start in $DELAY seconds."

for (( i=$DELAY; i>0; --i )) ; do
    sleep 1
done

#Record
beep
byzanz-record --cursor --verbose --delay=0 ${REGION} --duration=$D "$FOLDER/byzanz-record-region-$TIME.gif"
beep

notify-send "GIFRecorder" "Screencast saved to $FOLDER/byzanz-record-region-$TIME.gif"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you also want visible recordings of mouse clicks or key strokes, then screenkey is your best bet: https://github.com/wavexx/screenkey

Comment: I don't see how `screenkey` would handle mouse clicks (it seems to be for keyboard indication only), however, its README refers to `key-mon` which can do that, see my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/816081/6808) below.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple screen recorder in **2023** is the **gnome default screen recorder**.
It can record selected rectangle or full screen.
But it cannot record the specific window.
There is also no option to change the storage location of the recorded video.
You have to use dconf to change the setting `/org/gnome/gnome-screenshot/last-save-directory`

The vokoscreen-NG is still my main screen capture tool in 2023 so far due to its rich feature.

in 2023, most of the suggested software are either abandoned long time ago, or lack of ability to just record a section of the screen.

- kazam is not maintained since 6 years ago. (you can still see it in ubuntu ppa, but very buggy)
- byzanz also stopped 6 years ago.
- peek: It is [officially abandoned](https://github.com/phw/peek/issues/1191).
- <s>system default: can only record full screen and all screens you have.</s>

The only recent simple screencast app I can find in official repo is vokoscreen-NG. It is very actively developed and working towards wayland.

Then there is monster: obs-studio

Comment: "peek: can only record full screen and all screens you have." I don't think this is true. I can record small bits of the screen with peek.

Comment: Surprisingly, this is the correct answer. Peek can indeed record any part of the screen, but unfortunately it is now officially deprecated. It never got proper Wayland support and honestly it couldn't record GIFs at high framerates. [menyoki](https://github.com/orhun/menyoki) is the best alternative today, but it is unable to record a mouse pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gtk-recordmydesktop` and `ffmpeg` :

`apt-get install gtk-recordmydesktop ffmpeg`

Run RecordMyDesktop capture a portion of the screen/application to use as the screencast :

```
gtk-recordmydesktop
```

Create `ogv2gif.sh` with following content :

```
INPUT_FILE=$1
FPS=15
WIDTH=320
TEMP_FILE_PATH="~/tmp.png"
ffmpeg -i $INPUT_FILE -vf fps=$FPS,scale=$WIDTH:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen $TEMP_FILE_PATH
ffmpeg -i $INPUT_FILE -i $TEMP_FILE_PATH -loop 0 -filter_complex "fps=$FPS,scale=$WIDTH:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" $INPUT_FILE.gif
rm $TEMP_FILE_PATH
```

Use it :

```
./ogv2gif.sh yourscreencast.ogv
```

References :

- https://gist.github.com/fedir/56aeddde59571402a0d94f78eb6c7a5c
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35282/convert-ogv-video-to-gif-animation

Answer (score 1):

I test all above method, found the most simple one is:

1. use **gtk-recordmydesktop** and **key-mon** to get a ogv
2. **ffmpeg** -i xx.ogv xx.gif <-- **without any parameter**.

the fps is original, and the gif size is less than ogv file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach that I follow to record high-quality GIFs.

- Record the screen with a screen recorder such as Obs.
- Edit the video if necessary.
- Convert the video to a GIF using [GifTuna](http://giftuna.io/).