# My computer shuts down suddenly

Tags: power-management, shutdown

I have a little but annoying problem with my laptop. For quite some time my Asus K53SD (Xubuntu last LTS) 64 bits is shutting down without any demand when it have about 50% battery. I checked the power parameters (which I didn't touch) even if I see nothing wrong:

[image]

[image]

Perhaps, the system overvalue the real capacity of my battery?

Note: When I reboot my computer it shuts down immediately.

---

My battery is 'dead' (60 % dammage) according to Windows (CMD):

```
powercfg -energy
```

Comment: How did you create the animated gif?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast

Comment: Seems awfully like a dead battery. How old it is? I had exactly the same problem with a Toshiba laptop 2 years ago, and had to buy a new battery.

Comment: I bought it in 2013, almost two years ago. What is difficult for me to understand is that two weeks ago, I had not this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a few issues.  The battery itself could have an issue or defect in it, depending on how old the battery is.  I had a laptop I had when I was a lot younger that I always left plugged in and destroyed my battery so it couldn't hold a charge.

Also, how hot does your laptop get?  Laptops typically shut themselves down to prevent damage if they get too warm.  Take a look at your logs, usually there will be some kind of warning in syslog to hardware issues.

Comment: I don't think I have thermal problems but you know better : 

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +60.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +60.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +58.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter

Comment: The numbers don't look unusual... but the point I was getting at is that if you don't typically let your battery drain completely, you end up damaging the battery keeping it from holding a charge.  This is known as "solidifying your battery", which would explain why your battery dies at 60%.   Also, take a peek in /var/log/syslog and see if there is any mention of warnings.  Syslog cat's everything the system does.