# ImageMagick convert command to make a .gif from a large number of .xpm files

Tags: imagemagick, gif

I need to convert a large number (~10k) of `.xpm` files generated by my code to a `.gif` file.

I used ImageMagick as instructed here: [How to convert a PNG strip to a GIF?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636149/how-to-convert-a-png-strip-to-a-gif)

But my filenames are like `plot*.xpm`, * from 0 to 10000 and the convert command doesn't seem to understand it right and makes a `.gif` file with only a few frames.

[My `.xpm` files are like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3ovs.png)

they end somewhere with a non-random distribution of blue and green dots. (Like a circle of blue in the middle) in say 1000th frame. 
(I can't include it's picture because of posting limits)

[But this is the `.gif` file I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TePnl.gif)

I use this line of code:
`convert -loop 0 -delay 10 -page +0+0 /*.xpm output.gif`

I think I should use another method to introduce `.xpm` files to ImageMagick.
What should I do?

Comment: May you please mention the format of your file names (would be great to give few examples). And please include the exact code you used for converting. For those few files that you've converted already, is the result the same as you expected?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha I added screenshots and examples + the command used.

Comment: I am a bit confused. You want to put these `.xpm` in an animated `.gif` or you want to simply convert each `.xpm` file in to a non-animated `.gif`? if the first one is what you want, what is wrong with your current output?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha The first one. current output is not complete. It has only a few frames. I guess because file numbers vary from 1 to 10000 instead of 00001 to 10000 this happens. Am I using the right command?

Comment: I have made a set of pictures with the same name format you use and I noticed the problem is that the convert command is not able to sort numbers properly. So, it seems there is a need to convert filenames before starting conversion. I think actually all the pictures are converted but not in proper order. Should I share the command for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all of your pictures are converted but not in a proper order as you expect.

As per my experience, the `convert` commands cannot work with files with same filenames format you have used. It works on files with this sort:

```
file100
file10
file11
file1
file200
file20
file21
file2
...
```

So, you need to rename all your files before conversion. So, your filenames should become like:

```
file00001
file00002
...
file00010
...
file10000
```

This is what I have written. See if using it would solve your problem:

```
rename 's/plot(\d{1})\.xpm/plot0000$1\.xpm/' *  # plot#.xpm     >    plot0000#.xpm
rename 's/plot(\d{2})\.xpm/plot000$1\.xpm/' *   # plot##.xpm    >    plot000##.xpm
rename 's/plot(\d{3})\.xpm/plot00$1\.xpm/' *    # plot###.xpm   >    plot00###.xpm
rename 's/plot(\d{4})\.xpm/plot0$1\.xpm/' * # plot####.xpm  >    plot0####.xpm

convert -loop 0 -delay 10 *.xpm output.gif
```