# Periodically FTP upload screenshot possible?

Tags: bash, screenshot, capture

I'd like to take a screenshot every x minutes and upload it via FTP.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Found this, however it appears to have no possibility to do screenshots periodically: [Can we directly upload and share screenshots?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676269/can-we-directly-upload-and-share-screenshots)

Could I simly capture every x minutes triggered from a bash script?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Every piece of malware ever written has this functionality.  Check github.  It's implemented at least a hundred ways. "open source rootkit" is the search term.  They're written in various languages.  I'm sure I've seen this written in python.

Comment: Of course you can. Depends on where you need to share it to how you do this. Command line `rcp {file} {user}@server:/{dir}/`  is a method. You can also use sftp or ssh in similar fashion.

Comment: Read `man iwatch`

Comment: man iwatch: how do you mean I can accomplish this? Could you give me an example how to capture a screenshot and send it via iwatch? (iwatch - realtime filesystem monitoring program using inotify http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/iwatch.1.html)

Comment: found this here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/take-screenshots-in-ubuntu-at-regular-interval/   or here: https://g4greetz.wordpress.com/2016/09/15/how-to-take-screenshots-automatically-in-ubuntu/  . How to combine it to upload periodically via FTP?