# How to create animated gif screen captures like the Windows/MAC licecap app?

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop-recording

I'm looking for something to the equivalent of [licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).

It's an animated gif screen capture tool. I use it mainly for capturing QA bug reports during development.

Comment: Please take a look at the software Byzanz. There is a tutorial here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/record-screen-as-animated-gif-ubuntu/

Comment: Another option is SilentCast: https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast

Comment: Newest attempt is Peek for Linux >>> https://askubuntu.com/a/833995/11929

Answer (score 1):

Byzanz desktop recorder is available in the universe repository in Ubuntu 14.04 and later. Byzanz also allows recording of audio, when the output format supports it.

```
sudo apt install byzanz
```

Tto record from screen run the `byzanz-record`  command in the terminal with the following syntax:

```
byzanz-record -d DURATION --delay=DELAY -x X-COORDINATE -y Y-COORDINATE -w WIDTH -h HEIGHT YOUR-FILENAME
```

Example:

```
byzanz-record -d 20 --delay=6 -x 0 -y 0 -w 1200 -h 800 desktop-animation.gif
```

will record 20 seconds from a rectangular screen area starting at top left 0,0 with width 1200 and height 800 into a file named animation.gif with an initial delay of 6 seconds.

Comment: how wold i even find the proper coordinates? isn't there a gui?

Comment: yes there is one. you have to install this  script. check out this git repo  [byzanz_window](https://gist.github.com/noamraph/8348560).

Comment: there isn't just a one click installer?  thx

Comment: if you want a really simple one then please use [silentcast](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast) it's a good program with a gui.  you can install silentcast by copy and pasting this command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sethj/silentcast && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install silentcast`