# What are recommendable GIF screencast recorders?

Tags: software-recommendation, screencast

Asking out of curiosity, I seek alternatives to [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek) to directly record a screencast in a `.gif` format.

Are there other software that run well on Ubuntu 16.x that you can recommend me to take a look at?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create animated GIF images of a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command line tool called `byzanz` available in the official Ubuntu universe repository :

```
byzanz:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.0+git20160107-1
  Version table:
     0.3.0+git20160107-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

To install `byzanz`, just open a terminal and execute this command : `sudo apt install byzanz`

`byzanz-record` is a desktop recorder tool, which allows you to record the current desktop or parts of it to an animated GIF. Here are the instructions and application options from the Ubuntu Wiki how to use the tool : [Creating Screencasts - Making a GIF screencast](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CreatingScreencasts)