# sudo not asking for password of correct user

Tags: sudo

I have a new installation of 11.10. I have an admin user, and a standard user that doesn't have password with autologin. If I log in as the standard user, when I use sudo from command line, it asks for that users password, which doesn't work because that user has no password, and isn't admin. If I log in as admin user, it asks for admins password. How do I make sudo always ask for admin password?
Thanks,
CP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not how `sudo` works.  `sudo` asks for the users password and then checks if this user is a sudo user.

Options:

- If you want the 2nd user to be able to do admin tasks you need to add that user to the `sudo` group. See: [How do I add a user to the "sudo" group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/add-user-to-sudo-group)
- What you also can do (and probably are asking) is to use `su` 1st.

  Let's assume `rinzwind` is your `sudo` account. If you do

  ```
  su rinzwind
  ```

  and enter rinzwind's password you can then do

  ```
  sudo {command you need sudo access for}
  ```

  and it will ask for rinzwind's password for access to admin only things. 2 times exit and you are back on userlevel.