# Kubuntu asking for user password not admin password

Tags: permissions, sudo, password

When I try running applications or using `sudo` in konsole, the prompt sometimes asks for the user password, and then responds that it's not a sudo or administrator password.

It used to only ask for an administrator password.

It does sometimes ask for admin authentication. Additionally, it won't let me download from discovery any more.

I created a new user to check and the new user works like my current user account used to. I need the admin password to do certain actions, and it will always accept the admin password.

The one post I can see from before is [sudo not asking for password of correct user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117316/sudo-not-asking-for-password-of-correct-user) but it's almost 10 years old, and as I can see that I can use the admin password in other situations it'm not sure it applies to my situation.

Comment: I don't think that the password management for `sudo` has changed. In order to get elevated permissions (alias administrator's privileges), you should run `sudo command` and enter the password of your user (the same password used to log in). The settings in all Ubuntu flavours is that you cannot log in directly to the user `root` and there is no separate administrator password.

Comment: If you want to run as root, please be aware that it is risky. You can use **`sudo -i`**

Comment: Please post the exact commands you are typing into the Konsole and what is the exact output. `sudo` is expected to ask for your user's password.

Comment: Maybe *another program* (maybe even another computer for example the router) is asking for the administrator's password.

Comment: So since the initial post, without changing any settings that i'm aware of, i can now run programs and install/update from discover. I have no clue why.


someone asked what commands i ran, it was `sudo blob` obviously blob isn't a command, it was purely to test what was happening with sudo, it is still asking for my user password, although i can see that i would need to add myself to sudoers to make that work

Comment: @Plum, what you observe in this recent comment are normal features of `sudo`. You can run any command with sudo, and it means that you run it as the user `root` instead of your normal user ID. But for security reasons (to avoid damage by mistake) it is a good idea to use `sudo` only when necessary, that is when the normal user ID has no permissions (either to run the program or to read or write a file or a combination of those restrictions).