# How do I add myself into the sudoers group?

Tags: sudo, administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a user to the “sudo” group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-sudo-group)

I've added myself back into the admin's group I think, by following [this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

But I still can't do commands like:

```
sudo aptitude update
```

I get the message

```
oshirowanen is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

How do I add myself into the sudoers group now that I am in the admin group?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate ,But cant find it

Comment: @tachyons You might be thinking of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/73864/22949) about a similar but different error. There, a syntax error prevents running `sudo`. Here, entries may actually be missing. So I think an optimal answer here must also explain how to add the usual entries to allow administrators to use sudo. I've attempted [such an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/162873/22949). I do *not* recommend that this question be made a duplicate of [that one](http://askubuntu.com/q/73864/22949), because unlike with a "little" syntax error, answers there don't clarify how to edit.

Comment: After adding the user to the proper group, I still had to restart Ubuntu to get the updated group file to be recognized. Logging out and back in wasn't enough.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Login as root or `su` to get root prompt

type `visudo`

an editor will open find a line says

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

add one with your username below that

```
user ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Type `ctrl+x` Type `Y` to the prompt

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to `adduser <user> sudo` instead? I.e. have him be member of both `admin` and `sudo` group? I find it a bit redundant otherwise.

Comment: I agree. That would be the best solution in my opinion.

Comment: Also, `ctrl+x` doesn't exit the visudo. Rather `:wq`.

Answer (score 9):

If you're in the `admin` group (or the `sudo` group starting with Ubuntu 12.04) but that group isn't configured in `/etc/sudoers` to be able to run commands as root with `sudo`, you can fix that problem the same way you'd fix a *broken* `sudoers` file:

```
pkexec visudo
```

Then just edit the `sudoers` file to add whatever entries you need. In particular:

- Ubuntu systems before 12.04, or those that were upgraded from a version before 12.04, should have this:

  ```
  # Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
  %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
  ```
- Ubuntu 12.04 and later should have this (even if they also have the above lines because they were upgraded from an earlier release):

  ```
  # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
  %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
  ```

This [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) method works (on desktop systems) because Ubuntu systems with a GUI installed have two separate mechanisms for administrators to perform actions as `root`: [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html), and [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html).

See this question about a different but similar problem, if you're curious and want more information:

- [How to modify an invalid /etc/sudoers file? It throws an error and it's not allowing me to edit again to fix it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi)

Comment: The `%sudo` line existed already before 10.04. The only thing that's needed is to add the user to the `sudo` group (`adduser <user> sudo`). Still +1 for `pkexec`.

Comment: @0xC0000022L The `%admin` line exists too. This question is about a system where those lines have somehow been removed, commented out, or modified so they no longer work. You're right in that it's *arguably* a good idea to have the `sudo` line in `sudoers` files in Ubuntu releases prior to 12.04, but practically speaking, it doesn't matter much. In contrast, you *need* the `%admin` line on any system where users are made administrators by inclusion in the `admin` group, and you *need* the `%sudo` line on a system where users are made administrators by inclusion in the `sudo` group.