# How to login with root user?

Tags: permissions, login, sudo, root

I'm trying to do a login in my Ubuntu, but I can't:
[image]

I read Q&A about enabling root user, but how I can do it without a `sudoer` user? How can I add a `sudoer` user without having root access? I think it is a loop!

Comment: Did you try  [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124166/how-do-i-add-myself-into-the-sudoers-group) solution ?

Comment: @Lnux the first step for that solution is _Login as root or su to get root prompt_! I can't do it. It face me an Authenticatio Failure (Maybe because root is not enabled)

Comment: It's seems like your user **rcii** is not `sudoer`. Try adding this user to `sudo` group,  `adduser rcii sudo` or give this user sudo rights via `visudo` command.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu, the first user you create has sudo access. If that's how you are logged on, and you don't have sudo access, you must have messed up something. Boot from installation media, mount your root partition and edit `/etc/sudoers` to include your username (and/or edit your groups file to include your username to the `sudo` group).

By default, you cannot log in as **root** on an Ubuntu machine. There are lots of ways of changing this, but it's probably best if you don't until you can figure out how to do it on your own :)