# No root privileges - how do I add a user to the sudo list?

Tags: sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add user to “sudo” group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/add-user-to-sudo-group)

I do not have root privileges - how then do I add a user to the *sudoers* list?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but certainly more of a "puzzle" question rather than a real-world issue.

Comment: This is really a duplicate of [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user) rather than [How do I add a user to the “sudo” group?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-sudo-group)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allowing to modify the list of users allowed to perform super-admin tasks without requiring super-admin privileges would totally undermine the whole idea of using `sudo` - if anyone can add themselves to `sudoers` than anyone can become `root`. So there's no way to do what you want from inside the system.

Having said that, if you have physical access to the system, you can reboot into the recovery console or boot from a LiveCD, where you can get root access to the `sudoers` file.