# How to do GIF animations for instructions and learning purposes over GUI?

Tags: xorg, screencast

*I am trying to categorize many similar threads here.*

For example, I find this GIF animation freaking cool in this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/233710/74681). How can I do this kind of animations? How can I make sure it does not consume too much CPU with less CPU-intensive computers? How can I do professional screencast?

Answer (score 2):

Please, see the threads below.

**Unix Stackexchange**

1. [Creating a GIF animation from PNG files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/creating-a-gif-animation-from-png-files)
2. [Convert OGV video to GIF animaton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35282/convert-ogv-video-to-gif-animation)
3. [Are there any animation programs for animating static images](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13217/are-there-any-animation-programs-for-animating-static-images)

**Ubuntu Stackexchange**

1. [How to create animated GIF images of a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast/107735#107735)
2. [How to record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast?lq=1)

Comment: Reverse then here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12828048/54964 Work process here https://askubuntu.com/q/770165/25388