# Can I have a user execute sudo commands without being an administrator?

Tags: permissions, sudo, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a user to the “sudo” group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-sudo-group)

I recently became a UNIX admin for some relatives, and they are quite far up the creek on how to use ubuntu. I know that one key to UNIX administration is not to use the Admin account as little as possible, which I'm trying to enforce on their machine. I've looked at other articles regarding this, but they do the easy way out - changing the account to Administrator. *That is changing the permissions completely.* I want my **standard** user account to be able to execute **sudo** commands, but not be an administrator account. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If a user uses `sudo` it is essentially an Administrator.

Comment: ...But doesn't that allow you to do administrative commands without being administrator?

Comment: Semantics, if you use `sudo` you can do whatever you want in that machine, thus you're the Administrator.

Comment: The only dangerous part about being an administrator is that an administrator can use `sudo` and thus can make system-level changes. By allowing a normal user to use `sudo`, you are essentially making him an administrator just as dangerous as any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu has taken care of these issues for you, you don't need to worry about the Standard user or even the Administrator using the Super User priviledges all the time. In order to be able to use the `sudo` command, the `Standard User` needs to be listed in the `/etc/sudoers` file; the Administrator is automatically listed in this file. To add a user to this file, type the following command at the `terminal`:
`sudo nano /etc/sudoers`
You will see the following lines:
`%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`
Just add the name of the user who is to be able to use the `sudo` priviledges below these lines. To save the file, press `Ctrl` + `o` and to exit, press `Ctrl` + `x`.
Unless the user is listed here, she won't be able to use the `sudo` command, and it will return the error `"The user"(the user name) is not listed in the sudoers list. This incident will be reported.`