# Accessing sudo from a non-administrator profile

Tags: sudo, su

I have had Ubuntu for a few months by now, and I have set up an administrator profile and a 'normal' account, which I use for everyday work.

Sometimes I need the admin profile, e.g. to install programs. This means that I have to switch profiles, execute whatever commands I need with `sudo` through the admin profile and then go back to work.

This is rather uncomfortable, as sometimes I have got open web pages with the instructions of what I have to do on my work profile.

Is there a way to use `sudo` with admin username/password while I am still logged in as 'work'?

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Note that you can easily switch user sessions via Ctrl+Alt+Fn where n >= 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient way is to use the terminal where you can launch programs with admin privileges. There are 2 options:

1. **You can add your normal user to the group of sudoers**:

   ```
   sudo adduser normal-username sudo
   ```

   See [Can I have a user execute sudo commands without being an administrator?](https://askubuntu.com/a/234760/153278)

   Now you can execute commands in the terminal by writing `sudo command`
2. **Use your admin profile:**
   To use your admin profile in the terminal, you can `su` to that user, like `su admin-username` and then enter the admin user's password. If this doesn't work for the programs you want to run (it won't work for graphical applications), see this question:

   [How can I run an application with a GUI as admin from a non-admin user session?](https://askubuntu.com/q/164819/367990)

Comment: Hey, that's great! Thanks, it's just what I was looking for: open terminal --> su <admin> --> insert password --> do what you need to do! Have a nice day, Max

Comment: Adding a user to the `sudoers` group makes him theoretically already an admin user... :-/ That is probably not intended.