# How can I add an account to the sudo list?

Tags: sudo

I tried using this command in the terminal:sudo adduser liam sylvester sudo
but all it says is "Only one or two names allowed." My version is 12.04. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Or maybe a better one would be [How do I add a user to the “sudo” group?](http://askubuntu.com/q/2214/22949)

Comment: Usage is:`adduser USER GROUP` so add single user by `sudo adduser <username> sudo` to input *<username> as USER* and *sudo as group*. (according to usage of `adduser`)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file `/etc/sudoers` using the `visudo` command which checks for syntax errors before saving the file (and so protects your system):

```
sudo visudo
```

Search for the line `root ALL=(ALL) ALL` and add a new line below: `username ALL=(ALL) ALL`.

Comment: Please don't recommend that people (especially new users) edit `/etc/sudoers` directly. Also, a better approach would be to add the user to the `sudo` group instead of touching `sudoers`. That's the entire point of the group's existence.