# Sudo user not in sudo group?

Tags: sudo, users, adduser

When adding user like this :

```
sudo adduser someuser --ingroup sudo
```

Added user can use `sudo` but he is not in `/etc/group` sudo nor in `/etc/sudoers`
So how does it work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a user to the "sudo" group?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-sudo-group)

Comment: @Benny The question is not how to add user to the sudo group !

Comment: @Benny No way a dup of that. OP, good question. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `adduser` command sets the user's **primary group** to `sudo`.

From `man adduser`:

```
   By  default,  each  user  in  Debian GNU/Linux is given a corresponding
   group with the same name.       [ ... ]                  Users' primary
   groups  can  also be overridden from the command line with the --gid or
   --ingroup options to set the group by id or name, respectively. 

   [ ... ]  

   --ingroup GROUP
          Add the new user to GROUP instead of a usergroup or the  default
          group  defined  by  USERS_GID  in  the configuration file.  This
          affects the users primary group.  To add additional groups,  see
          the add_extra_groups option
```

The primary group normally has the same name and ID as the user. It is not stored in `/etc/group` but in `/etc/passwd`, like this:

```
bytecommander:x:1000:1000:ByteCommander,,,:/home/bytecommander:/bin/bash
```

The 4th `:`-separated field contains the GID (group ID) of the user's primary group.

Now `/etc/group` contains a list of all groups and associates users that have this group as additional (not primary) group, like this:

```
sudo:x:27:bytecommander
```

The distinction between primary and additional groups is also visible in the output of the `id` command (formatting by me):

```
$ id
uid=1000(bytecommander) 
gid=1000(bytecommander) 
groups=1000(bytecommander),27(sudo)
```

What is important for the use of `sudo` is only membership in the `sudo` group, it does not distinguish primary and secondary membership. The responsible configuration line can be found in `/etc/sudoers` and looks like this:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

This line grants all members of the `sudo` group automatically full permissions to run any command as any user, without having to specify each user manually.

Comment: So the best way to know all sudo users is by grepping sudo group id in `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd` ?

Comment: This command should show you all group members of the `sudo` group, no matter how they got in there, as it parses `/etc/passwd` to get all user names and checks the output of the `groups` command for each of them: `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 groups | grep ":.*sudo" | cut -d: -f1`

Answer (score 2):

The `--ingroup` option of `adduser` changes/adds the Primary group of the added user, and the primary group of a user is stored in the `/etc/passwd` file, in the `:` separated fourth field, as numeric GID.

So `sudo` is reading the `/etc/passwd` file, and finding that the user `someuser` has the primary group `sudo`, so the `sudo` commands are working perfectly.

Now, `/etc/group`'s `sudo` group entry still would not show the membership, because `/etc/group` only stores the secondary group membership, not primary.

Comment: +1 very nice,  good to know there is primary and other groups.

Comment: @EdiD There are _Primary_ and _Secondary_ groups, nothing else.