# Error: Username is not in the sudoers/No recovery menu to change password

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, password, data-recovery, recovery-mode

I can login to my Ubuntu 16.04 server no problem with my usual password but when I try to give admin privleges through terminal sudo -s, the password doesn't work. Strange because it always worked. I get the following error:

"Username is not in the sudoers file etc ...."

I did a search and it seems like a common error and recommend that go into recovery mode from grub.

http://www.tecmint.com/fix-user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-the-incident-will-be-reported-ubuntu/

But then there is no Recovery Menu that shows up (DOS window) from the grub recovery mode.

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is [only] with the sudoers file, you can find help at this Ubuntu help page,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)

The problem might also be with the /etc/group file, and in that case you can refer to the following link to another question here at AskUbuntu,

[How do I add a user to the “sudo” group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-sudo-group)

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it now. Luckily I had another account called test so I was able to log in there and change the sudoers file. Very strange why it went missing in the first place though!

Comment: I'm glad it works now, and thanks for sharing the solution :-)