# Ubuntu Server : Controlling the activity of multiple root users

Tags: server, permissions, root

I am hosting an Ubuntu Server on a high-end workstation for BioInformatics related analysis and would like to give root privileges to few more users as it will give them the freedom to install packages without having to wait for my permission.

1. Is there a way that I can provide root access to few users, but their activity will not interfere with other user accounts. i.e. Can the root privileges be restricted to a level that the modifications made by that user is "User" specific, but will not apply across the whole server
2. Is there an admin level above the "root" (.i.e.Super root) which will allow myself to administer the other root accounts during maintenance ?

Thanks

Comment: I can't recommend this, No, root is for all intents and purposes equivalent to God. There is no higher entity.  I think you are looking for https://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-sudo-group

Comment: Read `man sudoers` - you may be able to grant the users access to specific commands. If you want "the modifications made by that user is "User" specific,", you don't need `root`, just `User`. If they have `root`, they can affect the system, which affects other users.

Comment: Thank you very much. I went with sudoers- option to grating root access for specific commands.