# Applications using /sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point

Tags: 18.04

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 and receiving some errors like

```
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point: permission denied
/dev/mem : Permission denied
```

I have some executable and service which are running under a special user (non-root). They will try to access system bios info. So if I change ownership of above mentioned files by using command `chown`, will it affect any other system applications? Also, what are the applications using above mentioned files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing permissions of these system files is generally not recommended.
It'll adversely affect system functionality and other applications as well.

You can add your user to the group which owns the files/folder

```
sudo usermod -a -G group username
```

Comment: Thanks Sourav. Its working now

Comment: An [easy-to-remember](https://askubuntu.com/a/2218/349837) way is `sudo adduser <username> <group>`